# Add index settings to elastic search

Tags: django, settings, django-haystack, elasticsearch

How do I add index settings to `haystack` with elastic `backend`, like this guy has added in the question?

> [django-haystack autocomplete returns too wide results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008725/django-haystack-autocomplete-returns-too-wide-results?newreg=d281196f86094003ba42fe67d20faf33)

My `ngram` search is returning all the docs. When I rebuild my index the mapping is automatically taken from the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. This link can help in creating custom elastic search settings : https://wellfire.co/learn/custom-haystack-elasticsearch-backend/

You have to inherit ElasticsearchSearchBackend to make a new CustomElasticsearchBackend and set the custom elasticsearch settings dict in the init of that class.

There can be a lot more that can be done using the same idea. Like making the build_schema function to work differently. Also the Fields of haystack like CharField, NgramField, EdgeNgramField can be inherited to make custom fields to work for you.